# How to modify regex to to remove all strings followed by CR or LF

Tags: html, regex, notepad++

I want to get from the html  in  one  column frequency of transponders from the Hot Bird 13.0E satellites
link here: http://pl.kingofsat.net/pos-13E.php

This saved html page is huge with thousands of lines and is difficult to present as pattern. Easier way is to take short extract from that.

Here is  link to demo:
https://regex101.com/r/9k9NGA/2

In notepad++

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
 -  Find What:  `.*(\d{5}\.\d{2}).*` **defined frequencies**  
    *-Replace with: `$1`
    *- *check Wrap around*
    *- *check Regular expression*
*- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>       
**Here is part of code:**
`"basc_tp('m0')"><span class="nbc">11</span><a class="bld">Hot Bird 13C</a></td>        <td width="7%" class="bld">bbhg
10719.25</td><td width="2%" class="bld">V</td><td class="w3-hide-small" width="3%"><a class="bld"<td class="pos" dir="ltr">13.0&deg;E</td>  <td width="20%"><img src="/action_collapse.gif" id="im1" style="cursor: pointer" onclick="basc_tp('m1')"><span class="nbc">3</span><a class="bld">Hot Bird 13B</a></td>     <td width="7%" class="bld">
10727.00</td><td width="2%" class="bld">H</td><td class="w3-hide-small" width="3%"><a class="bld" href="tp.php?tp=225">111</a></td><td class="w3-hide-small" width="10%"><a class="bld" href="pos" dir="ltr">13.0&deg;E</td>    <td width="20%"><img src="/action_collapse.gif" id="im2" style="cursor: pointer" onclick="basc_tp('m2')"><span class="nbc">30</span><a class="bld">Hot Bird 13C</a></td>        <td width="7%" class="bld">
10758.00</td><td width="2%" class="bld">V</td><td class="w3-hide-small" width="3%"><a class="bld" href="tp.php?tp=5059">112</a></td><td class="w3-hide-small" width="10%"><a class="bld" href=="cursor: pointer" onclick="basc_tp('m3')"><span class="nbc">19</span><a class="bld">Hot Bird 13C</a></td>        <td width="7%" class="bld">
10775.00</td><td width="2%" class="bld">H</td><td class="w3-hide-small" width="3%"><a class="bld" href="tp.php?tp=227">113</a></td><td class="w3-hide-small" width="10%"><a class="bld" href=></table><div class="frqb"></div></div> <table class="frq"><tr bgcolor="#D2D2D2">  <td class="pos" dir="ltr">13.0&deg;E</td>   <td width="20%"><img src="/action_collapse.gif" id="im10" style="cursor: pointer" onclick="basc_tp('m10')"><span class="nbc">16</span><a class="bld">Hot Bird 13C</a></td>      <td width="7%" class="bld">
10911.00</td><td width="2%" class="bld">V</td><td class="w3-hide-small" width="3%"><a class="bld"`

**Here is part of code after:**
`"basc_tp('m0')"><span class="nbc">11</span><a class="bld">Hot Bird 13C</a></td>        <td width="7%" class="bld">bbhg
10719.25
10727.00
10758.00
10775.00
10911.00`

What should be add or change i  in sequence of expression : 

**`.*(\d{5}\.\d{2}).*`**   that it will also include whitespace characters (lookbehind)(CR and LF) to make futher operations .
When in the code appears the character LF or CR behind ".*" all characters and marks before are not included when appears LF or CR, and first  2 lines are not removed, why?

Comment: I feel you want to match `(\d{5}\.\d{2})|(?s:.)` and replace with `(?1$1\n:)`

Comment: I did this in 3 steps with Notepad++ in order to separate demanded frequencies <br> You gave me this solution in one step-thanks Working perfectly.I will have a good evening to check/analyze what wrong was with my approach.What more in regex101 is different engine I can't reach demanded output  and for  substitute supposed to be not `(?1$1\n:)`   but need more coffee to find a solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a 1-step approach to get a list of your values:

```
(\d{5}\.\d{2})|(?s:.)
```

Replace with

```
(?1$1\n:)
```

The regex pattern matches and captures into Group 1 five digits, dot and 2 digits, or just matches any char. The replacement pattern is a conditional that replaces the found match with Group 1 and a newline if Group 1 is matched, or with an empty string (if any other char is matched). Note that `(?:)` may be removed if you select *`.` matches newline* option.

Comment: One-Step approach for taking the result for any matches defined in the regex-Very  Impressive & Very valuable code if You know where and how. I am still happy with alternation with The Vertical Bar   `|(?s:.)` to mark all parts before and after selection and to use in similar cases like that.and really thanks for that remarks:`.` or `?:`- working as well with only `.`